# Metro App UI ProgressRing does not update and UI hangs

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a button named `bExecute` and it's `Click` event handler has this body:

```
try
{
    // Activate the progress ring
    prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    prProgress.IsActive = true;
    bExecute.IsEnabled = false;

    // Some Task
    DoTask();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Do Something
}
finally
{
    // Stop the progress ring
    prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    prProgress.IsActive = false;
    bExecute.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This method has these problems:

- The **UI** appears to **hang** until the task is completed and then resumes as per
  normal.
- ProgressRing never appears to be activated.
- The bExecute Button never appears to be Enabled/Disabled.

I can wrap `DoExecute()` in a `Task.Run()` method, this frees up the **UI**, but then you never see the `ProgressRing` and nor do you see `bExecute` being Enabled/Disabled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `DoTask()` is a CPU intensive method taking a long time to complete. The way you're doing it now, it executes on the UI thread and blocks. You should wrap it in a `Task.Run()` call as you suggested, but you need to `await` it, otherwise the rest of your event handler will be executed before the task completes.

Try rewriting your event handler like this:

```
private async void bExecute_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Activate the progress ring
        prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        prProgress.IsActive = true;
        bExecute.IsEnabled = false;

        // Some Task
        await Task.Run(() => DoTask());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop the progress ring
        prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        prProgress.IsActive = false;
        bExecute.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was sooo close. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score -1):

Which event handler ? why there's no catch body ? `ProgressRing` never appears to be activated because `finally` body makes it collapsed & `IsActive = false` and `bExecute` disabled. So `bExecute` Button never appears to be enabled. `DoTask` method is so much faster than you can't see the changes.

```
try
{
    // Activate the progress ring
    prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    prProgress.IsActive = true;
    bExecute.IsEnabled = false;

    // Some Task
    var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    dispatcher.RunAsync(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => DoTask());
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
finally
{
    // Stop the progress ring
    prProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    prProgress.IsActive = false;
    bExecute.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: The code takes atleast 20 seconds to complete. So I know that isn't the issue.

Comment: The UI thread is currently blocking, so forcing Dispatcher.RunAsync WILL not help either. And YES, I have tried this.